# Using Jquery how can I refresh a CSS transition effect with one click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

Here is my code thus far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".KD").click(function(){
    $("p").load('KD.html');
    $(".video").load('KDVideo.html');
    $(".synopsis-change").toggleClass("synopsis");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
  });
});
```

It seems to work with multiple clicks, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with only one.  Do u know what am I doing wrong?   Thank you for your support.  :-)

Here is the css:

```
synopsis  {
font-size: 2px;
-webkit-transition: font-size 10s ease; 
}
.synopsis-change {
font-size: 18px;    
}
```

Comment: Why would you toggle a class, just to immediately toggle it again?  I don't follow what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you be more specific, and explain the problem you are having more thoroughly?

Comment: I'm trying to use the same CSS transition for multiple classes and even multiple times for the same class, so I figured I'd have to reset that transition after using it each time.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  What do you mean by "transition"?  What are you transitioning to/from?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically with a click, I'm trying to fill a box with text and transition the letters from small letters to larger ones over time.  I had success doing this by toggling two classes but I'm having trouble doing it over and over again.  Maybe I'm using a totally wrong approach?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add extra class to set the animation, http://jsfiddle.net/2Lf3D/

```
<span class="KD">click to start animation</span>
<div class="synopsis font-animation">****</div>
```

---

```
.synopsis  {
font-size: 2px;
}
.synopsis-change {
font-size: 18px;    
}
.font-animation{
-webkit-transition: font-size 1s ease; 
}
```

---

```
$(".KD").click(function() {
    $(".font-animation").toggleClass("synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");    
});​
```

Comment: it would be better if down voter can justify the reason for the down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what are you trying to accomplish, but here's the tip.

The timing may be an issue there. The code is being executed from top to bottom, but it's possible that these 2 commands are overlapping since they are really simple and are executed nearly in the same time.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".KD").click(function(){
    $("p").load('KD.html');
    $(".video").load('KDVideo.html');
    $(".synopsis-change").toggleClass("synopsis");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change").delay(100);
  });
});
```

Or this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".KD").click(function(){
    $("p").load('KD.html');
    $(".video").load('KDVideo.html');
    $(".synopsis-change").toggleClass("synopsis");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
    },100);
  });
});
```

... to delay changing the second class and see if it works.